# Get characters between two exact pipe | character in unix

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

I need to grep all characters between **second** and **third** `|` (pipe) character from a file.

Let's say we have a file with string like below (two lines):

```
abc123 | def123 | ghi123 | jkl123 | mno123
abc123 | def123 | jkl123 | ghi123 | mno123
```

After I use grep/sed/awk command I should get like

```
ghi123
jkl123
```

I would appreciate any clue or help.

Comment: And what did you try ?

Comment: A clue: `cut -d '|' -f 3`

Comment: If it is *all characters* between 2nd & 3rd pipe, you missed the spaces before & after `ghi123` & `jkl123`...

Comment: `awk -F'|' '{gsub(" ",""); print $3}' file`

Comment: Thank Jidder,it is very close to my answer but in output seems spaces gone? I need to get string as it is, how is it possible ? Found that awk -F'|' '{ print $3}' ab.txt ... Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry. I thought you wanted the spaces removed. Looks like you worked it out anyway though :)

Comment: you could try `sed -r 's~^.*\|.*\|([^|]*)\|.*\|.*$~\1~g;s/^ //g' file`

Answer (score 3):

If you want always to get third element, you can try with:

```
echo "abc123 | def123 | ghi123 | jkl123 | mno123" | awk -F " | " '{print $5}'
```

Or:

```
echo "abc123 | def123 | ghi123 | jkl123 | mno123" | cut -d '|' -f 3 | tr -d ' '
```

Output:

```
ghi123
```

For a string with many words between `|` you can use:

```
echo "abc123 | def123 | foo bar | jkl123 buz | mno123" | cut -d '|' -f 3 | sed -e 's/^ //' | sed -e 's/ $//'
```

Output:

```
foo bar
```

Note that `sed -e 's/^ //' | sed -e 's/ $//'` is used for removeng first and last whitespace, because `tr -d ' '` removes all whitespaces from the string.

Comment: Well it is not always one word,strings could be like below abc1323 abc123 | bdc123 bdc123 bdc123 | jkl123 jk ... So i need all strings between second and third pipe

Comment: wouldnt it be `{print $3}` ?

Comment: @Jidder Unfortunately not, because `|` are also counted

Comment: `awk -F'|' '{gsub(" ",""); print $3}' file` why does this work with $3 without the spaces ? I know what the command does as i wrote it. But i'm interested in why this doesnt count the | ?

Comment: @hek2mgl Is that why its `$5` because its actually delimiting on spaces and | ?

Comment: @Jidder I thought I were sure about this but currently don't think I'm sure anymore. That's why I deleted the comment. I'm still trying to find it out :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Not sure if you found the answer yet. Its because awk is recognising `|` as an `or` sign. Putting it within square brackets seems to solve the problem. Multiple characters find the string but regex needs making literal. Backslashing it also doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Double backslashing the pipe seems to work. It appears that it is parsed twice :)

Comment: @Jidder YEAH! :) You made it! please post it as an answer :) Now, after reading the `awk` man page sections of `FIELDS` and `REGULAR EXPRESSIONS` it is clear what is going on. `-F' | '` will select only the space as delimiter, or better spoken `space or space`. This is because a multi-character delimiter will be threatened as a regular expression.